# Nested schemas with zod, using node.js, express and typeorm

Tags: node.js, express, typeorm, zod

I am developing an API for study purpose, that currently involves two entities: 'product' and 'productDetail', establishing a bidirectional one-to-one relationship between them.

```
@Entity("products")
export default class Product {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
  id: number;

  @Column({ length: 60, unique: true })
  name: string;

  @Column({ type: "text", nullable: true })
  description?: string | undefined | null;

  @Column({ default: 0 })
  stock: number;

  @Column()
  price: number;

  @OneToOne(() => ProductDetail,
   (productDetail) => productDetail.product)
  productDetail: ProductDetail;
}
```

and

```
@Entity("productDetail")
export class ProductDetail{
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("increment")
    id: number

    @Column({length:50})
    color: string

    @Column({type: "decimal", precision: 10, scale: 2})
    weight: number

    @Column({length: 100})
    dimensions: string

    @Column({type: "text", nullable: true})
    otherDetails?: string | undefined | null

    @OneToOne(()=> Product, (product) => product.productDetail,
    {onDelete: "CASCADE"})
    @JoinColumn()
    product: Product 
}
```

My goal is to receive this json body, and create one instance for product and another for productDetail:

```
{
    "name": "product",
    "stock": 10,
    "price": 100,
    "productDetail": {
        "color": "white",
        "weight": 50,
        "dimensions": "dimensions_test",
        "otherDetails": "details"
    }
}
```

For that, i create the productCreateSchema, that i want to nest productDeatailSchema, keeping the productDetail key optional

```
const productSchema = z.object({
  id: z.number().positive(),
  name: z.string().max(60),
  description: z.string().nullish(),
  stock: z.number().positive().default(0),
  price: z.number().positive(),

});

export const productCreateSchema = productSchema
    .omit({ id: true})
    .extend({productDetail: productDetailSchema.optional()})
export const productUpdateSchema = productCreateSchema
    .partial()
```

productDetailSchema:

```
export const productDetailSchema = z.object({
    id: z.number().positive(),
    color: z.string().max(50),
    weight: z.number().positive(),
    dimensions: z.string().max(100),
    otherDetails: z.string().nullish()
});
```

However, when i parse the above body, i received this response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "productDetail": [
            "Required"
        ]
    }
}
```